# how to access a variable from another class using interface in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I've two class autoCompleteTextfiled.java and BillingController.java.

AutocompleteTextFilled is a custom class. When I select a popup I'm getting result.

**code is below:**

```
private void populatePopup(List<String> searchResult) {
    List<CustomMenuItem> menuItems = new LinkedList<>();
    // If you'd like more entries, modify this line.
    int maxEntries = 10;
    int count = Math.min(searchResult.size(), maxEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        final String result = searchResult.get(i);
        Label entryLabel = new Label(result);
        CustomMenuItem item = new CustomMenuItem(entryLabel, true);
        item.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                setText(result);
                selectedTextFromMenu(result);
                entriesPopup.hide();
            }
        });
        menuItems.add(item);

    }
    entriesPopup.getItems().clear();
    entriesPopup.getItems().addAll(menuItems);

}
 private void selectedTextFromMenu(String result) {

    AutoCompleteTextField autoCompleteTextField = new AutoCompleteTextField();
    ItemSelectedListener mListener = new BillingController();
    autoCompleteTextField.registerOnGeekEventListener(mListener);
    autoCompleteTextField.selectItemListener(result);
}
public interface ItemSelectedListener
{
     void getSelectedResult(String result);
}
public void registerOnGeekEventListener(ItemSelectedListener mListener)
{
    this.itemSelectedListener = mListener;
}


public void selectItemListener(String result)
{

    if (this.itemSelectedListener != null) {

        itemSelectedListener.getSelectedResult(result);
    }
}
```

but i trying to access a result from BillingControllerClass to AutoCompleteTextFiled returns null.

```
 @Override
public void getSelectedResult(String result) {
    System.out.println("The pin has been changed>"+billingItemDetails.size());//billingItemDetails retunes 0
    for (int j= 0; j<billingItemDetails.size();j++)
    {
        ItemListRequestAndResponseModel.item_list item_list = billingItemDetails.get(j);
        if (item_list.getItem_name().equals(result))
        {
            System.out.println("The pin has been changed---->"+result);
            txtFieldId.setText(item_list.getShort_code());//Textfiledis retunes  null

        }
    }
}
```

}

But billingItemDetails(Arraylist) retuns 0. But initially ArrayList have a data.

Please Help me.

Comment: how about either return string from getSeectedResult or send static refrence of your textField

Comment: Thanks @Yuuuucef but i have 4 textfield

Comment: @Yuuuucef noooo to static references ;)

Comment: then what i would use is use a static reference for exemple :
`public static TextField field1;
public static TextField field2;
public static TextField field3;
public static TextField field4;
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
// initiliase from fxml 
field1 = textField1; // and so on 
     }`
then you can access it from the other class by the static refrence 
`classname.field1.setText("text");`

Comment: please search this site: there are literally hundreds of similar questions ... some with excellent answers!

Comment: @Yuuuucef statics are __evil__ - if you want to improve your coding skills do some research to learn why :)

Comment: @kleopatra i use them only when needed and it work great for me with the little complexity and ressource consumption

Comment: @Yuuuucef they are nearly always the wrong choice of option, rarely "needed" (as in 0.00001%) but then ... if you insist on doing stuff wrong, your decision ... <shrugs> - just do not spread the wrongness

Comment: @kleopatra i do not insist we are all here to learn i will do more research